# Strange way to declare variable Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered this way of declaring variable on internet but can't really see its effect

```
some_variable:str = 'abc'
```

it doesn't seem to change the data type as first guess.

```
test_var:str=1
```

The type of variable still int as test with

```
type(test_var)
```

what actually is this?

Comment: type declaration is only for IDE not for interpreter. It has no functional effect, just to suggest you correct methods for particular object.

Comment: type hints...  [pep 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)

Answer (score 1):

This is "type checking". Its effectiveness will depend on your IDE's capabilities. It has nothing to do with runtime behaviour.

For example:

```
x:str = 0
```

The type hint suggests that *x* should only ever refer to a *str* type. However, here we assign zero (an *int*). At runtime the assignment will take place as written. However, your IDE may highlight a potential issue.

Type hinting has limited use in my opinion. Here's another example:

```
def afunc(s):
    i:str = s
    return i
def bfunc():
    return 0
    
afunc(bfunc())
```

In this case the variable *i* will be assigned *int* at runtime but the IDE cannot detect any potential problem. [caveat: Pylance in VSCode can't detect the problem. Other static type checkers may be more intelligent]

Comment: They are also very useful for automatically generated documentation, and there are some CI/CD tools that make use of them as well

Comment: Type hints can be very useful. Check out frameworks like fastAPI for elegant use of type hints https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#recap